# Конфликт работы якорный ссылки и javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Переход по якорной ссылке работает только один раз. После этого одного раза просто закрывается менюшка без перехода( речь о мобильной версии). Если js убрать, то переходы идут нормально, но остаётся открытой менюшка.

```js
$('a.small').click(function() {
  var layout = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout');
  layout.MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.light_green-orange.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <div class="mdl-layout-title">
          <img style="height: 50px" src="LOGO-SD.png">
        </div>
        <span class="mdl-layout-spacer"></span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#main">Главная</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#timetable">Расписание</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#tasks">Задачи</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#extratasks">Сверхзадачи</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Контакты</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Регистрация</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer mdl-layout--small-screen-only">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title" style="color: black;">Игронет</span>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link small" href="#main">Главная</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link small" href="#timetable">Расписание</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link small" href="#tasks">Задачи</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link small" href="#extratasks">Сверхзадачи</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link small" href="">Контакты</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link small" href="">Регистрация</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <div class="page-content">
        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div id='main' class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" style="margin: auto;">
            <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
              <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">
                                    «ПРОФЕССИИ БУДУЩЕГО»
                                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
              <p><b>
                                        ОБРАЗОВАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ФОРУМЫ
                                        ДЛЯ ПОДГОТОВКИ ИГРОТЕХНИКОВ
                                        «ПРОФЕССИИ БУДУЩЕГО»
                                        РОССИЙСКОГО ДВИЖЕНИЯ ШКОЛЬНИКОВ
                                    </b>
              </p>
              <p>Наша главная задача не передать вам знания, наша задача побороть ваш страх перед незнанием, научить вас учиться.</p>
              <b>Участники:</b>
              <p>250-300 человек, педагоги, студенты, специалисты по работе с РДШ</p>
              <b>Фокус-группа:</b>
              <p>300-400 детей в каждом регионе</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__media mdl-cell--middle">
              <img src="air_professii.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
              <a style='color: white;' class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
                                    Зарегистрироваться
                                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div id='timetable' class="mdl-layout-title" style="margin: auto; color: black;"><b>Наше расписание:</b>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-grid mdl-cell--middle">
          <div class="mdl-cell--2-offset-desktop mdl-cell--8-col-phone mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div style="color:white;" class="mdl-card__title mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
              День 1
            </div>
            <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">
              <li class="mdl-list__item">

                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Открытие
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Пленарное заседание
                              </span>
              </li>
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Брейн Фитнес
                              </span>
              </li>
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Обучение игровым кейсам и практикам
                              </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div style="color:white;" class="mdl-card__title mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
              День 2
            </div>
            <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Практикум в школах региона по отработке игр
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Обучение игровым кейсам и практикам
                              </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-cell--2-offset-desktop  mdl-cell--8-col-phone mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div style="color:white;" class="mdl-card__title mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
              День 3
            </div>
            <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Практикум в школах региона по отработке игр
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Тренинги по выстраиванию образовательных и карьерных траекторий
                              </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-cell--8-col-phone mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div style="color:white;" class="mdl-card__title mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
              День 4
            </div>
            <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Подведение итогов
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Оформление договоров на аттестацию робототехников
                              </span>
              </li>
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Подписание соглашений
                              </span>
              </li>
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Торжественное закрытие форума
                              </span>
              </li>
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                                Культурная программа
                              </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div id='tasks' class="mdl-layout-title" id='tasks' style="margin: auto; color: black;"><b>Наши задачи:</b>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div class="mdl-cell--2-offset-desktop mdl-cell--8-col-phone mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div class="left-top">1</div>
            <div class="text">Подготовка 10 -15 новых профориентационных игр и использование игр из «Атласа новых профессий»</div>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-cell--8-col-phone mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div class="left-top">2</div>
            <div class="text">Обучение педагогов и активистов, работающих с РДШ 3 компетенциям:
              <br>-проведение тренинговых и активных образовательных форм работы;
              <br>-проведение конкретных кейсов деловых игр и отработка на фокус-группах;
              <br>- принципы создание собственных деловых игр;
              <br>- обучение работе с атласом новых профессий.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-cell--2-offset-desktop mdl-cell--8-col-phone mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div class="left-top">3</div>
            <div class="text">
              Формирование профессионального сообщества игротехников, создание собственных кейсов игр
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-cell--8-col-phone mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div class="left-top">4</div>
            <div class="text">
              Проведение чемпионата игротехников, запуск профессионального движения игротехников в образовании
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div id='extratasks' class="mdl-layout-title" style="margin: auto; color: black;"><b>Сверхзадача:</b>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div style='margin: auto' class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div id="canvas">
              <p class="task first left">Включение РДШ в работу с Атласом Новых Профессий (фактически привнести атлас в каждую школу)</p>
              <p style="margin-top: 60px" class="task second right">Создание интерактивной формы образования (в перспективе могут осуществлять сами школьники по принципу старшие-младшим)</p>
              <p style="margin-top: 60px" class="task third left">Формирование в школах и педагогической среде повестки НТИ</p>
              <p style="margin-top: 40px" class="task fourth right">Создание готовой программы ежедневной работы для актива РДШ в регионах</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="mdl-mega-footer">
        <div class="mdl-mega-footer__middle-section">

          <div class="mdl-mega-footer__drop-down-section">
            <input class="mdl-mega-footer__heading-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked>
            <h1 class="mdl-mega-footer__heading">Партнёры</h1>
            <ul class="mdl-mega-footer__link-list">
              <li><a href="http://www.ranepa.ru/">РАНХиГС</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://alterschool.com">Школа Будущих Президентов</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="https://asi.ru">Агенство Стратегических Инициатив</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="https://www.oprf.ru/">Общественная палата РФ</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://kremlin.ru/">Администрация Президента РФ</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://xn----ctbbfgafpccvblxfoe7o3c.xn--p1ai/">Российское движение школьников</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-mega-footer__bottom-section">
          <div class="mdl-logo">Школа Будущих Президентов</div>
          <ul class="mdl-mega-footer__link-list">
            <li><a href="#">О нас </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </footer>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в onclick='' каждого элемента меню прописать `window.location="index.php#main"; var layout = document.querySelector(".mdl-layout");layout.MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer(); return false;` всё будет работатью

Comment: А вы как сами думаете, кто нибудь в этой каше верстки стал бы разбираться?)) `Минимальный рабочий пример` всегда делайте. Иначе это никому не надо

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, никто и не просил разбираться в куче верстки. А для демонстрации работы якорных ссылок эта вёрстка очень себе неплохо подходит. Тем более что js код заботливо вынесен в сторону..

Comment: Заботливо)) Все равно не требуется столько кода. Если задаете вопрос укорачивайте его, и упрощайте для понимания. Даже все что у вас находится в `<head>` просто лишнее а там уже 23 строчки. Это лишь просьба. ответ то вы задали, значит другие должны его прочитать и вникнуть в проблему. Это больше уважение к другим

Comment: @ВасилийБарабашев, укорочу как смогу. Дейчтвительно, Вы правы)

Comment: Начинали с `jquery` - а закончили `onclick`. Нельзя же так.

Comment: Если в вопросе `jquery` - то и решение должно быть на нем же.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, начинать с чистого а заканчивать jquery - плохой тон. А вот в упрощении с jquery до чистого ничего плохо не вижу. Тем более иных вариантов так и не появилось